# How to check if a pre-built package exists on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, prebuild

I am trying to install `gtk-pixbuf 2.61.1` but it says that it is missing a `TIFF library`, from the [gnome site](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-building.html) it says to

> Before installing these libraries from source, you should check if your operating system vendor has prebuilt packages of these libraries that you don't have installed

I am new to `Ubuntu` and am not sure how to check if such pre-built packages exist, before going to install them from source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `apt-cache search` to find the library that you need.

on my system I have Debian, the differences are small e.g.

```
$ apt-cache search libtiff dev
libtiff5-alt-dev - Tag Image File Format library (TIFF), alternative development files
libtiff5-dev - Tag Image File Format library (TIFF), development files
libtiff4-dev - Tag Image File Format (TIFF) library (old version), development files
```

When you find your library, you will need to install it:

```
 $ apt-get install libtiff5-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
    dpkg --get-selections
```

to list all the packages installed by Ubuntu on your system. Take a look at this link http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/show-the-list-of-installed-packages-on-ubuntu-or-debian/